# Why do my villagers keep starving to death?

Tags: banished

Here is my setup, and i have gone through 2 starvation cycles.  I have plenty of food production sources, and my workers live close to their workplace, I have reassigned them as i expand.  I don't get why i'm always having a shortage.

I read another post where someone said 3 gatherers, 2 hunters, and 2 fisherman fed their population up to 80 people...

http://heegar.net/images/starvation_why.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows that you only have 108 food. With the fact you've got two recent deaths it's highly unlikely that you're meeting the minimum requirements for the amount of food actually needed by your colony. You should be able to observe this better by looking at the graphs section on your town hall screen at food storage over time - it will be very low and constantly hit zero.

With this in mind, you need more food production, whether this be additional fishing or additional fields and more farming, or whatever.

It's worth keeping in mind that certain types of food production yield in different ways - fishing and gathering results in a steady quantity of food incoming while fields and orchards result in a (hopefully) large yearly yield. It's no point going all in with farming unless your food supply is already stable as it will be a full year before you get any food out of it.

The bottom line, though, is: your people are starving to death because you're not producing enough food.

Comment: I definately see the bottom line, and thank you for the response.  I have reassigned everyone to food production and have no other workers but I still don't catch up on my food production.  Wondering if I Need to demolish homes so people don't increase too fast - does that work?

Comment: Yes, your population is largely influenced by available housing. More housing should pretty much always be your last priority.